# Package Installation error in Virtual Environment

Tags: 16.04, package-management, python3, environment

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. So I created a virtual environment for python and activated it using

`cd /entire_path_to_virtual_env/bin`

`source activate`

After that I used:

`pip3 install nltk`

The installation completed successfully, yet when I import it, it gives error that there is no module named nltk. So what is the correct procedure to install packages (nltk) in my virtual environment?

Comment: These problems are often due to pip3 installing in a different version that you are using when you get the error.

Comment: @StephenRauch what is installing a different version? I am a total newb in linux so can you help me out with more details?

Comment: I could, but I do not have time right now.  This basic question has been asked and answered on Stack Overflow many times.  Try python -V to see which version you are using.  Try `which pip3` and `which python` to see where they are installed, likely they are not matching.  You can also try `python3` or just `pip` and maybe align that way.

Comment: @StephenRauch Thanks a lot man..it imported in python3..now I have to figure out how o import in idle..if you get time and write the answer I will upvote and accept it..thanks again